# Latency and the payload size for WCF Service

Tags: wcf

How to measure Latency and the payload size for IIS hosted WCF Service?

Comment: How is hosted your WCF Service? Self hosting or IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if you are using AspNetComaptibility or not. If you are then it is simple, you can use ASP.NET performance counters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx

Especially look at **Request Bytes In Total** and **Request Wait Time**